# Gnome clipboard buffer

Tags: gnome, clipboard, copy, paste

Since Ubuntu Gnome replaced Unity in 17.10, I'm having trouble copying and pasting.  I've read the [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100756/how-to-increase-clipboard-size) about adding an extension and have seen other sites recommending applications to manage this.

Isn't there a way to increase the Gnome copy/paste buffer size without these?

Thanks.

Comment: I've attempted to use several of the managers in the article, but most don't solve the issue or even work.  Surely there's a way to change this manually in some config file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Ubuntu (18.04 LTS) it seems like they increased the buffer size or fixed something, because I can now paste large selections without issue.  No added extensions necessary.